# В UI tableview картинки загружаются не сразу, а после переиспользования ячеек

Tags: xcode, swift

У меня есть таблица. В ней кастомные ячейки. В каждой ячейке есть ImageView для аватарки. Аватарка грузится с интернета. Для загрузки аватарки в эту вьюшку использую следующий код:

```swift
cell.avatarIMG.layer.cornerRadius = cell.avatarIMG.frame.height / 2
cell.avatarIMG.clipsToBounds = true
let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: post.useravatar!)!
let imgData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL)!
cell.avatarIMG.image = UIImage(data: imgData)
```

Когда загружается экран с таблицей, я получаю данные, потом перезагружаю таблицу и данные выводятся на экран. Всё норм, но аватарки сначала без картинок. Но стоит поскроллить вниз, дальше всё норм. И если вернуться в начало там тоже всё норм, аватарки все работают и картинки есть. Методом тыка я выяснил, что если из кода убрать строку:

```swift
cell.avatarIMG.clipsToBounds = true
```

То всё работает нормально. Но с этой строкой картинки появляются только после переиспользования ячейки.

Что самое интересное, в седьмой версии xcode этой проблемы не было. Она появилась только после обновления до 8 версии.

UPD: пока писал вопрос, параллельно нагуглил, что проблема в баге восьмого xcode. Когда я запрашиваю высоту фрейма imageview, то мне возвращается 1000.0, в результате высчитывается неправильный радиус, и из этого вытекает проблема с отображением. А после переиспользования ячейки размер уже получается правильный, вот поэтому тогда радиус становится правильным и картинка отображается.

Но как тогда достать правильную высоту ImageView?

Answer (score 1):

Попытался воспроизвести проблему, но безуспешно. Делаю в точности, как вы, и у меня все работает корректно (аватарки с картинками отображаются сразу, а не после переиспользования). У меня стоит XCode 8.1. Попробуйте и вы обновиться до последней версии - возможно, Apple в ней как раз это и пофиксила.

Comment: Я после того как до 8 версии обновился столько нервов себе помотал с разными глюками и конвертациями, что теперь боюсь обновлять дальше))

Comment: Второй XCode можно параллельно первому поставить, ничего страшного не будет. Все равно рано или поздно придется обновиться :-)

Comment: Не знал о таком. Надо будет попробовать. Спасибо)